# How the arrow function is preventing re-rendering in the code

Tags: reactjs, onclick, rendering

The following code holds the query,

```
import React,  {useEffect , useState} from 'react'
import './Body.css'
export default function Navbar() {
    const  [value , setvalue] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("useEffect ran");
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <button onClick={ () => setvalue(value-1)}> - </button>
                <button> {value}</button>
                <button onClickCapture={() => setvalue(value+1)} > + </button>
            </div>
        </>
    )
```

When I am using `onClick= {setvalue(value+1)}` then I am getting an error for too many renderings.

But, when I am using an arrow function then it is preventing the renders.

Can you tell me how is it happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```html
<button onClick={setvalue(value-1)}>
```

You are adding as the handler of `onClick` the result of the call function `setvalue(value-1)`.

It is equivalent to calling `setvalue(value-1)` in the body of the component and using its return value in the `onClick`, like this:

```
export default function Navbar() {
    // ...
    const resultOfCall = setvalue(value-1);
    
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <button onClick={resultOfCall}> - </button>
```

And this errors because `setvalue(value-1)` changes the `value` state, which is in your JSX in `<button> {value}</button>` (so it changes every time the render/component function is called).

## The fix

When you do instead:

```html
<button onClick={() => setvalue(value-1)}>
```

You are adding as the handler of the `onClick` a function that, when executed, calls `setvalue()`. And such function will be executed when the user clicks the button.

Comment: One question, when you say  `(so it changes every time the render/component function is called)` should it be called when I click the button? And what property of the arrow function is used so that I can prevent rendering? Means I know when I am using the arrow function button function will work only when I click it, but why is it doing so?

Comment: Consider this: `onClick={arg}`. What `onClick` expects as `arg` is a function. When you have `onClick={setvalue(value-1)}` what you are passing as `arg` is the result of the call to `setvalue(value-1)` which is `undefined` because `setvalue(value-1)` returns nothing (try it out: `console.log('hello: ' + setvalue(value-1))`). This is the first issue in your code.

Comment: Oh! I got it now onClick expect function but setvalue is not. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is a function which adds to numbers

```
function addNumbers(a, b) {
    return a + b
}
```

to see the result you need to use

```
console.log(addNumbers(3,4))
// or
alert(addNumbers(3,4))
```

now, how these things work?
the `addNumbers(3,4)` returns the result, and then it console logged in the browser console `console.log(7)`.
so the `console.log()`runs the result of `addNumber(3,4)`, this line is very important to keep in mind.

now, what your code `onClick={setvalue(value+1)}` is doing, is `onClick={1}`,
your code runs before `onClick` event runs it, resulting too many error renderings.
now if you use an arrow function `onClick={() => setvalue(value+1)}`, it basically is a wrapper just like `console.log(addNumbers(3,4))`,
`setvalue(value+1)` sets the state, and then on click it returns the value.
I hope you got your answer.